# Ruby key / value for each loop debug

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

For various reasons I have a chef recipe that I want to use add multiple groups to a system with. I've defined a data bag with a key / value structure that provides the group name as the key and the guid as the value  eg:

```
{
    "id": "default_groups",
    "group": {
     "sales": "200",
     "marketing": "800",
     "csr": "1000",
     "devel": "9000",
     "scientists": "500"
    }
  }
```

I was wanting to use the group resource in a for each loop but I don't seem to be referencing the data in the data bag correctly:

```
user_groups = data_bag_item('groups', 'default_groups')

%w{"#{user_groups['group']}"}.each do |usr|
  group "#{usr}.key" do
    action :create
    gid "#{usr}.value"
  end
end
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong with my syntax?

The error output from the chef run is as follows:

```
ERROR: group["#{user_groups['group']}".key] (cookbook_groups::recipe_groups line 10) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '3'
   ---- Begin output of ["groupadd", "-g", "\"\#{user_groups['group']}\".value", "\"\#{user_groups['group']}\".key"] ----
   STDOUT:
   STDERR: groupadd: invalid group ID '"#{user_groups['group']}".value'
   ---- End output of ["groupadd", "-g", "\"\#{user_groups['group']}\".value", "\"\#{user_groups['group']}\".key"] ----
   Ran ["groupadd", "-g", "\"\#{user_groups['group']}\".value", "\"\#{user_groups['group']}\".key"] returned 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot combine string interpolation, word arrays and array/hash access like that.

This might work:

```
user_groups = data_bag_item('groups', 'default_groups')

user_groups['group'].each do |key, value|
  group key do
    action :create
    gid value
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `%w` does not do what you think:

```
▶ %w{"#{user_groups['group']}"}
#⇒ ["\"\#{user_groups['group']}\""]
```

You probably need just:

```
user_groups['group'].each
```

or like.